# Uncoupling glued PVC joint

Tags: pipe, pvc, pool

[image][image]I must repair a busted 2" PVC pool pipe.  I have cut out the section of pipe that is broken due to the winter freeze.  Is it possible to break the glued joint and what is the method?  I was thinking to use my dremel and cut the outside pipe down to the good joint in several places then attempting to chisel away the bad pipe.  Thanks for any advice.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what was there before you cut it? It looks like a coupler glued close to the elbow, with a very short piece of pipe joining them.  Was that a prior repair?  And you cut the coupler?  If so you need to cut *off* the whole coupler and ream out the little bit of pipe.  Carefully,  because if you mess up you won't be able to salvage the elbow, you'll have to remove tee further back.  Can you add a wider shot?  There might be easier ways not invovling a reamer.

Comment: Correct.  A coupler joined two elbows and a short piece of pipe was used each side of the coupler.  The 2nd elbow not shown in mirrored to the one shown.  The coupler was the "low" point in the system where the rupture occurred.  Instead of a coupler in the repair, I plan a coupling with a half inch connector to be used as a drain as suggested in the Answer below.  I would like to be able salvage the couplings at either the outlet or inlet of the elbows.

Answer (score 3):

Most of those glues/adhesive are solvent type, they weld the two pieces together.

There are tools/reamers to remove a broken pipe from inside a joint, but think you will need to grind/sand that pipe away carefully.

It might be easier to find a section to add a coupling and replace everything after it.

If that section of broken pipe is in good condition, might use a reducer/expander joint/coupling and glue it over the top of the broken pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I have had *reasonable* success with applying heat to the pipe (I use an electric heat gun of the sort commonly used for stripping paint) and being able to remove the remaining pipe (destructively) from the socket (leaving the socket usable.) The pipe turns somewhat "rubbery" while the fitting is still hard, and can then be peeled away with pliers. If you overdo it and distort the fitting, it won't work.

There are also "socket saver" tools to drill out the pipe stub, ranging from budget ones for the homeowner on up to professional versions at professional prices. Those mostly make sense for things like a drain connection in the wall of a house where cutting it out is going to involve a lot of trouble and expense to access the pipe and replace the fitting.

If you are trying to remove the remaining part of the broken fitting without damaging the pipe stub, that won't work with the tools or the heat method, as far as I know. Those will work to remove the pipe stub from the elbow, but not for the remaining bit of fitting on the outside of the pipe stub, leaving the pipe stub usable. I could envision a tool for that, but I don't think anyone makes it.

Otherwise, the usual cheaper solution for exposed piping is to cut out the fitting, buy a new fitting and a coupling, and and replace the whole area. Evidently this would be several fittings in this case before you get to plain pipe, so you might want to try removing the pipe stub first.

*In the interest of not having to do this another year, include either a drain valve or a union that you can open in the fall to this section of pipe when you rebuild it.*

Comment: Is that Schedule 80 pipe?  Patrick you can tell by reading the markings.  Ecnerwal you can probably tell from the photo :) but I can't.  Because even the moderately expensive socket savers won't work on Schedule 80.     And I've never tried de-welding a pipe with heat but I wonder if using a hacksaw to cut the pipe into segments like an orange first, from the inside, and heating each segment one at a time, would improve your chances of not damaging  the elbow?

Comment: @jay613 - heat gun/holesaw vs pvc/abs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQGHej71nWE  Not sure about schedule 80 though